# Is there a "Restore Down" event in VB.NET

Tags: winforms, vb.net-2010

What event would fit when I click the "Restore Down" button in the title bar then it restores down the main form together with the other form with the specific size I declared. 
I am new to vb.net and still exploring new functions. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologizes for c# solution, perhaps this will help you to convert it to [VB.Net](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb). I don't know any better solution available but this should work.

```
private FormWindowState? previousWindowState;
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Bounds == this.RestoreBounds && previousWindowState.HasValue && previousWindowState.Value == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Restored down");
    }
    previousWindowState = this.WindowState;
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
}
```

Comment: It gave me some idea. I put my code in the else condition. It worked. Thanks for the help (: @Sriram

Comment: @user3105280 If this post answered your question, please click on the check mark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted Srirams answer to vb.net

```
Private Sub MotionManagerDialog_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    If Me.Bounds.Equals(Me.RestoreBounds) And Not PreviousWindowState.Equals(Nothing) And
                        PreviousWindowState.Equals(System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized) Then
        ' Captures restore down action
    End If
    PreviousWindowState = Me.WindowState
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Wylie's answer: You also need to declare PreviousWindowState somewhere:

```
Dim PreviousWindowState As FormWindowState
```